First order system transfer function
Suppose we have the transfer function written in the picture. The circuit from which this transfer function was derived is a classic RC circuit with an Rload (Rload parallel to the capacitor).
I have calculated the DC gain K and time constant tau.
1) I would like to ask if the frequency calculation is correct or not.
2) I calculated the blue dot like this: at DC the chondesator is open, so I delete it and H(s) = Rl/(Rl+R) = 5/6 --> log(5/6) = -1.61dB
(don't look at the x axis of the Bode diagram, which I drew at random.)
Did I do something wrong in the calculations?



There's some missing details. Could you include a schematic? I'm assuming you're using "normal" topology but where is $R_L$?

It's bad form to refer to reference designators on components without a schematic, but if the schematic is what I imagine it to be, your calculations look basically correct.  Another way to do it would be to find the Thevenin equivalent that the capacitor sees, then write the transfer function by inspection.

Is that 1303 or 1503 Hz in your handwriting?

@Andyaka it's 1909 Hz

@Colin Hi. I uploaded the schematic because a friend of mine passed me the notes.

Thanks for the picture. Now I know that this is a passive filter rather than an active one. So your transfer function is not including your capacitor. I also recommend using the Laplave Domain.

@Colin I've used Laplace domain and that is the final result. In the transfer function there  are "s" and "C"
